# How to check if firewall rule exists via Powershell, if not, pause script until it does?

Tags: powershell, azure, rule

Straight up, I'm new to the coding world, so please forgive my ignorance. I have cut/paste some code to try and mock something up myself, but I'm sorta stuck.

I have a Powershell script that runs an Azure ARM template via Custom Script Extension to install a firewall rule, and I have another .ps1 script that I wish to run only if the firewall rule has been enabled/installed.

I have discovered that you can deploy 2x ps1 scripts via Custom Script Extensions, but they both run at the same time, hence why I want the 2nd to only continue/start once the firewall rule has been detected.

Here is what I have so far to test if the rule exists or not:

```
$text = 'Hello World'
$r = Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName 'MY FIREWALL RULE NAME' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ; if ($r) {$text | Set-Content 'c:/temp/found.txt'} else {$text | Set-Content 'c:/temp/not-found.txt'}

#This sections is the continuation of the script when the rule has been found
$text | Set-Content 'c:/temp/helloword1.txt'
```

So what I'm thinking is if it has not found the rule, then pause/repeat until it does, once it has found the rule, then continue/start the script.

*Disregard my helloworld/found/not-found.txt files, as mentioned, I was using these to fill in the gaps to figure out if the rule is found or not.*

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to sleep until a specific rule is found you can use:

```
while (-not (Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $RuleName -EA Silent)) { sleep 1 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just something like this (EDITED):

```
while (!($r = Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName 'MY FIREWALL RULE NAME' -ErrorAction Ignore))
{ Start-Sleep -s 1 }
```

Comment: a `while(){}` will not sleep if it's found the first time.

Comment: Yes but he may want to save it to variable, the answer to which I realised right after saving lol

Comment: while both are right, sadly i couldn't make them both right. but thanks! does the ! mean the same as -not ?

Comment: Basically, yeah. They might not both work in all the same places but they do the same thing.